# Is there a way to take Screenshots from a DS?

Tags: nintendo-ds

The title pretty much explains it all - I want to be able to take screenshots from my DS, but haven't been able to find out whether it is possible and affordable.

Comment: I would be interested in this as well.  I usually resort to taking a picture of the DS with my phone.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://www.pressthebuttons.com/2010/07/isnitrocapture-yes-it-is.html

Hate to break it to you, but it's in the $3,000 range.

Comment: In that case, I guess a follow-up question is in order: do you have 3000$ to spare?

Comment: hehe.  I'm trying not to eat so that I can still afford to pay off the bills this month :D

Comment: Screenshots from any handheld console are always taken from either the development kit or a special version of the hardware that outputs to a computer.

Answer (score 4):

Currently, no there is not.     :(

 
      However, you can get various NDS emulators for the PC, and take screens from those.

Comment: You'd prolly end up DLing roms to get the shots you want though.

Comment: You would have to download the ROM(s) from the web or your DS cartridge.

Answer (score 3):

There must be *some* means of getting video output from a DS, because G4TV and GameTrailers include gameplay video in their reviews, and there's no way they're playing the entire game in an emulator. And they're definitely not just filming the screen, because you can see effects of the stylus without seeing the stylus in front of it.

It's possible they have special hardware from Nintendo, or they may have in-house modders crafty enough to figure out where to solder a video cable to the motherboard. You might want to try asking on the GameTrailers forums how they record their videos of DS gameplay.

I also found this article on [Nintendo DS on your TV](http://www.siliconera.com/2006/08/24/play-your-nintendo-ds-on-your-tv/), but it's really old (August 2006) and it says in an update that the device was a prototype that was never actually sold.

Comment: Game Reviewing companies get special hardware that is not commercially available to achieve this.  :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Try using [nds-bootstrap](https://github.com/DS-Homebrew/nds-bootstrap) or [TWLMenu](https://github.com/DS-Homebrew/TWiLightMenu) from GitHub. [nds-bootstrap](https://github.com/DS-Homebrew/nds-bootstrap) is a bootstrap program to boot NDS roms that can be dumped from your cartridge. TWLMenu is a menu that can be used on a flashcard to boot these NDS roms. Check the [wiki](https://wiki.ds-homebrew.com/twilightmenu/) for the way to install and setup this. When [TWLMenu](https://github.com/DS-Homebrew/TWiLightMenu) is installed, you can open the nds-bootstrap menu to make a screenshot. Press `L`+`Down`+`SELECT` to open this menu. Now click on `Take screenshot...` And then select the right VRAM bank and press `a`. Whola! Now a screenshot is made. Then you can find the screenshot in: `fat:/_nds/nds-bootstrap/screenshots.tar` On the flashcard. Or try the app on 3DS if you have one.